# Meaning of mentioning current of a power source

Tags: electric-current

If I connect a load to a DC supply of 230 V, the load draws the current it needs according to Ohm's law. Then what is the meaning of mentioning current in addition to voltage in  some power sources? (for example: A 5V 2A mobile phone charger)

Answer (score 1):

The power supply has a (constant) voltage output of 5V and the maximum current that it can supply is 2A.

Comment: Isn‘t this due to the internal resistance of the power supply?

Comment: 2.5 ohms is rather high for the internal resistance of a power supply.